# Script task inside a SSIS For Each loop - writing to a file

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

My script task is inside a SSIS for each loop. I want the script task to write some dynamic string to one file only for all iterations. After every iteration, the file should get appended, not overwritten with the current value of the dynamic string. Its like a logging "tool". Btw, SSIS is SQL server integration services, an ETL tool.

How do I do this ?

I tried using a script, but it seems to be overwriting the file with the dynamic string. I don't want that. I want it to be appended to the file instead.

Here is the script which is inside my for each loop -

```
String text = "My text here";
String path = @"C:\Data\TextFiles\logFile.txt";
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path, true);
file.WriteLine(text);
file.Close();
```

Comment: @gunr2171 - okay, thanks. I will try it now. Got an example here - http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-appendalltext

Comment: @Jonesy - Are you running the code inside SSIS with the given conditions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like a much easier approach is to use [`File.AppendAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx), or one of the other variations in [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string text = "My text here";
string path = @"C:\Data\TextFiles\logFile.txt";

System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, text);
```

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx):

> Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

Comment: Okay, I will try this soon. But, just to remind you, this script is running inside a for each loop of SSIS.

Comment: @blasto, for a normal c# program, this will work just fine. I do not know if SSIS will affect this.

Comment: Shouldn't matter where the script runs from, .NET is .NET

Comment: Do I need to do any critical closing operations like file.Close(); in your example ?

Comment: @gunr2171 - I get an error - System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'my path here' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: @blasto, it sounds like you have the parameters backwards.

Comment: @blasto, as for the question `Do I need to do any critical closing operations`: no. The function returns a void, so you can't do anything more. Read the description, it will close the file for you.